# url with FTP port set to 22 for a Web Request is not working

Tags: c#

I tried to set the port to 22 this way(variable _ftpPort). But I get the error "The underlying connection was closed: The server committed a protocol violation."

Port 22 is usually linked with SFTP, not plain FTP. Would it be possible to construct my url with ftp on port 22?

```
 FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + _ftpUrl + ":" + _ftpPort + 
_ftpChangeDirectory + "/" + ftpFileName);
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password);
            request.UsePassive = "TRUE";
            request.EnableSsl = "FALSE";
            request.UseBinary = "FALSE";

            using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
```

Comment: Construct that string separately, and assign it to a string variable.  That will give you the opportunity to examine the entire string to see if it is malformed.

Comment: Port 22 is usually linked with SFTP, not plain FTP. Are you sure you don't want to use that and you really have a normal FTP server in a non-standard port?

Comment: Robert Harvey. How do we construct a string separately for the port number to be 22? Than you

Comment: Thank you very much @Alejandro it made sense to use SFTP.